# apache spark predictProbabilities not a member NaiveBayesModel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

when i do sbt package or sbt assembly i get error like :

value predictProbabilities is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayesModel

but same code  works in my spark-shell

/home/user1/spark-1.5.2/bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0

i use spark-1.5.2 and scala 2.10.4  sbt 0.13.8

i use centos 6.5 linux

i do see predictProbabilities  in this link.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayesModel

I don't know if sbt assembly or io.prediction is required or not
But I tried it. It makes no difference. Get same error.

Has anyone come across such problem.
If so can you let me know the solution.

Thanks!

my code is

==========================================================

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.{NaiveBayes, NaiveBayesModel}

import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

val trainData = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "file:///home/user1/nbtest/trainData.nb.svm")

val testData = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "file:///home/user1/nbtest/testData.nb.svm")

val model = NaiveBayes.train(trainData, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")

val predictionAndLabel = testData.map(p => (model.predict(p.features), p.label))

val accuracy = 1.0 * predictionAndLabel.filter(x => x._1 == x._2).count() / testData.count()

val testDataFeatures = testData.map(p => p.features)

val probabilities = model.predictProbabilities (testDataFeatures)
```

===================================================================

my /home/user1/nbtest/build.sbt is like this

=============================================================

```
name := "testBayes"

version := "1.0" 

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / ""

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.databricks"  % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.4.0"

libraryDependencies += "io.prediction" % "core_2.10" % "0.9.6"

libraryDependencies += "io.prediction" % "sdk" % "0.5.0"   

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
```

=============================================================

i have in  /home/user1/nbtest/project 
assembly.sbt
plugins.sbt

assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Warn
```

=============================================================

Comment: Would you care explaining to me what do you think your sbt file does ?

Comment: i do sbt package to build the target jar file which i run using spark-submit.

Comment: My question is what does it do ? I know what is sbt. I'm just trying to help you figure out your issue.

Comment: sorry i did not understand.

Comment: first i tried with this in build.sbt

Comment: name := "testBayes"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / ""

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.4.0"

Comment: when trying to solve this error "value predictProbabilities is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayesModel " i tried different other options in the sbt to see if it works. i could not figure out why it works in my spark-shell but  sbt package gives the above mentioned error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library instead the spark-mllib 1.4.0 that you are using :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark"  % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "1.5.2"
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it looks pretty bad on my part. Thanks eliasah.

Comment: sorry, this is my first post. i did not know. i accepted.